# Personal part collection on the web (Bricklink or alternative)

Tags: piece-information, organisation

I started using Brinklink a few months ago and although I like it, the interface is quite terrible. I'm looking for a specific feature but don't know if it's unsupported or just I cannot find it.

How can I create my personal parts collection on Bricklink, something like a catalog of parts that I have? Other options I require would be adding parts from whole sets and adding bricks from my placed orders.

If this cannot be done please suggest alternative websites or even desktop applications that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to using BrickLink for those purposes would be http://rebrickable.com. I personally find the interface to have some warts, but definitely better than BrickLink in a lot of ways. In particular to your requested features it does support importing parts from sets (Look for the "Add to my Parts (Part out set)" link on any set description page) as well as importing from Bricklink Orders in XML format and a few other sources. If your long term plans involve selling some of those parts on BrickLink it also supports a decent set of export options that can help out with that as well.

Comment: Brickset.com has a feature that I can't yet see on rebrickable, a way to easily get a list of "Not Owned" sets here: http://brickset.com/mycollection/sets Plus, you can change the format of the set lists.

Comment: The specific reason that I didn't mention Brickset is that while it has really excellent set collection features it has no real capacity for general part management. The question explicitly asks about parts management which would seem to disqualify Brickset then. Thanks for mentioning it though.

Comment: Ah yes... good point. I sure wish Peeron was still up to date. It's weird.. every time I go there new stuff has been added... though now the last added is from 1 January. So sad.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I do use Brickset sometimes, I added the sets I own and update this list often but haven't used any of the other features and couldn't find some sort of part catalogue there. Because essentially what I need is to keep a list of single bricks I got from Bricklink or some lots. Rebrickable seems promising, I have visited that site few times but didn't have a clue it has this feature. Will check in detail when I get home so this will probably be accepted answer.

Comment: @gev - I had completely forgotten that Peeron had parts inventory management! I haven't seen anything official but it seems like they are doing inventory updates quarterly these days. Rebrickable does appear to be updated more regularly but perhaps you could add another answer with Peeron as an option?

Comment: I will check out Peeron too on the weekend (even thou it looks like someones first HTML test from the 90s), thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It appears rebrickable is usable for what I needed, thus this answer is accepted. Although there are some options missing but I haven't had the time to inspect whole website in depth so I might have missed them.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve what you want to is register as a seller. You don't have to sell anything (you could keep your store open but empty, or you could just keep your store closed).

Once you have a seller account you can manage two stockrooms: A and B. If you do have some sets/parts you are planning to sell and want to have an active store, you can keep those items in stockroom A, and you can keep your own personal collection in stockroom B, which is invisible to buyers, even if your shop is open.

This way you can easily manage your collection, automatically keep track of how much it is worth, and also, if you decide to sell, all you have to do is move the items from stockroom B to stockroom A, open your shop and you are done. ;)

Comment: Perhaps you could expand the answer by explaining to OP how to register as a seller? The question seems to stem from this lack of understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I did think about this as a possible solution, but then again I thought that registering as a seller would require some pay-pal or bank account or more personal data. So the first comment is totally in place. Am I wrong about these, what are the requirements to register as a seller?

Comment: I went looking this morning and you start the registration from http://www.bricklink.com/regCountry.asp?a=SN where you select your country. The next page has quite a lot of information to input, but does not actually require that you input any financial information immediately. I set up my store a long time ago so cannot proceed on that form, and the help files don't have enough detail so it is unclear when or if you have to register your PayPal account or if that prevents entering inventory.

Comment: I will check this option too although if it requires paypal to accept payments that will be a problem because only paying via paypal is supported in my country.

Comment: @PSIXO - As I'm already registered I can't go back to the registration screen, but BrickLink doesn't take any of your financial information. BrickLink is operated completely separately from PayPal or other payment methods. It is up to you, as a seller, to choose your payment options later, and even then you will have to send out invoices manually, or instruct the buyer how to pay through their chosen payment method. So the point is you don't need to give BrickLink any sensitive information.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I didn't have the time to test out the Bricklink "Hidden Seller" approach but based on what you say I guess things a was considered whit would not be a problem.